# Is it possible to persist data from a form on the github pages into the repo

Tags: github, github-pages

I'd like to use github pages to persist data from a form into the github repo for a project and would like to know if this is possible with github pages.

If not are there ways to persist data from a formular on the github page website into a database or maybe service?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like FireBase, that allows you to send and retrieve data using javascript.

https://firebase.google.com/